# Conditional subset based on one occurrence

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, subset, longitudinal

I would like to subset a database like this in two parts:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
ins =c(1,2,3,4,5,3,2,4,5,8,9),
Ytx = c(NA,NA,1998,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2011,NA))

ID ins  Ytx
  1   1   NA
  1   2   NA
  1   3 1998
  1   4   NA
  1   5   NA
  2   3   NA
  2   2   NA
  2   4   NA
  3   5   NA
  3   8 2011
  3   9   NA
```

The first should look like this (all the values coming after the occurrence of Ytx grouped by ID):

```
 ID ins  Ytx
  1   3 1998
  1   4   NA
  1   5   NA
  3   8 2011
  3   9   NA
```

and the other one made by what is left:

```
ID ins  Ytx
  1   1   NA
  1   2   NA
  2   3   NA
  2   2   NA
  2   4   NA
  3   5   NA
```

Thank you for your support

Comment: did you mean after instead of before?

Comment: @chinsoon12 yes, AFTER. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, we can use `ave` and `split`. This will divide data into list of two. First one is the data before value of `Ytx` and the second one is rows after `Ytx`.

```
split(df, with(df, ave(!is.na(Ytx), ID, FUN = cumsum)))
#Or if you may have multiple Ytx per ID
#split(df, with(df, ave(!is.na(Ytx), ID, FUN = cumsum)) > 0)

#$`0`
#  ID ins Ytx
#1  1   1  NA
#2  1   2  NA
#6  2   3  NA
#7  2   2  NA
#8  2   4  NA
#9  3   5  NA

#$`1`
#   ID ins  Ytx
#3   1   3 1998
#4   1   4   NA
#5   1   5   NA
#10  3   8 2011
#11  3   9   NA
```

Comment: Thk you very much @user3962914 !

Answer (score 2):

Two other alternatives with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
# convert 'df' tot a 'data.table'
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# alternative 1
split(df, df[, !!cumsum(!is.na(Ytx)), by = ID]$V1)

# alternative 2
split(df, df[, !!Reduce(`+`, !is.na(Ytx), accumulate = TRUE), by = ID]$V1)
```

which both give:

> ```
> $`FALSE`
>    ID ins Ytx
> 1:  1   1  NA
> 2:  1   2  NA
> 3:  2   3  NA
> 4:  2   2  NA
> 5:  2   4  NA
> 6:  3   5  NA
>
> $`TRUE`
>    ID ins  Ytx
> 1:  1   3 1998
> 2:  1   4   NA
> 3:  1   5   NA
> 4:  3   8 2011
> 5:  3   9   NA
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)[, rn := .I]
idx <- df[, 
    if (any(!is.na(Ytx))) 
        .I[seq(.N) >= match(TRUE, !is.na(Ytx))]
, ID]$V1
```

`df[idx]`:

```
   ID ins  Ytx rn
1:  1   3 1998  3
2:  1   4   NA  4
3:  1   5   NA  5
4:  3   8 2011 10
5:  3   9   NA 11
```

`df[-idx]`:

```
   ID ins Ytx rn
1:  1   1  NA  1
2:  1   2  NA  2
3:  2   3  NA  6
4:  2   2  NA  7
5:  2   4  NA  8
6:  3   5  NA  9
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
    ins =c(1,2,3,4,5,3,2,4,5,8,9),
    Ytx = c(NA,NA,1998,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2011,NA))
```

Comment: Thank you @chinsoon12 for your help!